# Data Science education curriculum design and guidelines in Computer Science and other Disciplines

Tags: data, education

I am studying data science education curriculum design and guidelines. All resources I have up to now is about data science in statistics education and library and information science education.

Is there any work on data science in computer science/software engineering education (adding data science courses to a traditional software engineering curriculum) ,management and other disciplines?

An example of including the curriculum for statistics is this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266856309_Data_Science_in_Statistics_Curricula_Preparing_Students_to_Think_with_Data)

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit?  What resources have you found, and what do you mean by: **Is there any work on data science in computer science/software engineering education (adding data science courses to a traditional software engineering curriculum) ,management and other disciplines**  ?

Comment: I mean how computer science curriculum have been enriched by data science skill set. For Example, adding statistics and visualization courses.

Comment: Data Science is a huge domain in itself. So, it cannot be added as a curriculum in any curriculum.

However, computer science can include distributed computing which would help the students understand and appreciate the idea of distributed systems and Big Data.

Comment: I agree. this was the reason I mentioned data science skills not the whole data science concepts.

Comment: We've actually proposed a StackExchange site to specifically help with CS-related education questions like this one. Come support us here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators?referrer=9Z3MnermjDx7JWcMHelYkQ2

Answer (score 2):

Yes, data science work do exist in domains of management and computer science.

I think data science is a huge domain in itself to include in any of the curricula. So, I would explain how data science is used in the domains:

1. **Management:** 
   Data Science used in a lot of ways. I use data science and analytics in every phase of the customer acquisition and retention funnel; which includes designing models for using the customer event tracking data and identify patterns and predict churn. Here is an [example article](https://moz.com/devblog/deep-learning-for-customer-churn-prediction/) from the Moz blog, which explains about the use of deep for churn prediction and customer retention.
2. **Computer Science:** 
   Most of the data science has roots in computer science basics. However, including the concepts of distributed computing would help the students understand and appreciate the concept of Big Data, when they later enter the industry.

So, I think data science is a huge domain in itself, and has it's share of unique applications in a wide range of domains. However, bulk of data science concepts and techniques have taken roots in math, stats and computer science basics and concepts. So, I think the knowledge of those domains would be helpful and suffice.

So, these are some links which can help in curriculum re-design for accommodating data science concepts in the management and CS curricula:

1. MBA speciality.
2. [Curriculum of the Data Science and Business Analytics program](http://www.scu.edu/business/graduates/current-students/data-science.cfm) at the Santa Clara University.
3. [Curriculum](http://dsi.virginia.edu/curriculum) of the Masters of Data Science in Virginia University.

The third bullet is something very close to how data science can be included or blended with the Computer Science degree.

Comment: I know conceptual relationships. I am looking for papers or reports of curriculum redesign to put data science skills in computer science or management. An example of doing this job for statistics is this:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266856309_Data_Science_in_Statistics_Curricula_Preparing_Students_to_Think_with_Data

Comment: I couldn't find any nice papers on that. But, by observing the curricula of the top programs around the world, where data science is successfully blended with main-stream business and Computer Science, I highlighted three such curricula which I found very impressive and nicely done.

Comment: The point is statisticians explicitly mentioned their curriculum drawbacks in different papers and suggested new courses and skills to add to a traditional statistics curriculum . Moreover, they raised new viewpoints for teaching well-established courses. But such phenomenon is not seen for computer science curriculum.

Answer (score 2):

It seems computer science programs have not changed their curriculum. They just added some elective courses for data science or probably adding a concentration to let students reinforce their skills on data science and big data.

Comment: I agree with you.